# Openxlsx writeData() throwing XML error but write_xlsx() does not

Tags: excel, xml, openxlsx

I have a df with various columns, some are character based, some numeric, some are a blend of the two. There are strings in some of the columns that have punctation in them, such as "()", and some may have numbers blended in, like so: "Random string 7/19/2023".

I'm using the openxlsx package to create a new wb with a new sheet name and then writing the df to that workbook. Here's the code:

```
file <- createWorkbook('New Workbook.xlsx')
addWorksheet('Test Sheet Name')
writeData(file, sheet = 'Test Sheet Name', df)
```

However, the problem is that when I go to open this workbook, I get the excel error message below:

"Removed part: /xl/sharedStrings.xml part with error. (Strings) illegal xml character. Line 100 column 183"

What's unusual is that if I use the write_xlsx() function, like below, then the file opens with no problems at all.

```
write_xlsx(df, "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Random File Name.xlsx")
```

It seems as if there's something going with openxlsx's writeData() function that's not happening with write_xlsx() and is causing this error.

Anyone have any ideas on why this is happening and how to go about fixing it?

Comment: Probably some special character is not correctly escaped. One of your characters might be something like `&` or `<`.

Comment: Hi Jan, I was able to identify the issue when I open the xml doc in VS Code. It's a "stx" ASCII that's causing the issue. I tried using gsub('[:punct:]', '', df$col) to fix the issue but no luck. Do you know why writeData() would handle this differently than write_xlsx()? No worries if you don't.

Comment: As far as I remember both use a different set of XML creation functions. `writeData()` writes to the workbook which is a bit different, compared to `write.xlsx()` which dumps everything into the output file. But it might be something different. The takeaway is tht both functions don't have much in common. Btw, I'm the author of `openxlsx2`, if you fancy a more modern approach.